# Nustache.Mvc - Is it possible to create a custom helper

Tags: nustache

I use The Nustach.MVC assembly https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nustache.Mvc3/1.13.8.22 so I can share templates betwixt back end and front.

Is there a way to write a custom handlebars helper that I can use in the back end?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this Project could help you [nustache-helpers](https://github.com/buildingblocks/nustache-helpers)